# InvalidOperationException: <result xmlns=''> was not expected

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I'm doing a request to server, which returns the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result><category>...
```

I am using the following code to deserialize:

```
private ListCategories DeserializeXML()
        {
            XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ListCategories));

            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("CategoriesListXML.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            {
                return (ListCategories)xml.Deserialize(fs);
            }
        }
```

And i have the following for my class **Categories**

```
[Serializable]
    public class ListCategories
    {
        public List<Categories> CategoriesList { get; set; } = new List<Categories>();
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class Categories
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int parent_id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string image { get; set; }

        public Categories() { }
        public Categories(int id, int parent_id, string name, string image)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.parent_id = parent_id;
            this.name = name;
            this.image = image;
        }
    }
```

But when I deserialize the xml document I get a problem in this line:

```
return (ListCategories)xml.Deserialize(fs);
```

> InvalidOperationException: `<result xmlns=''>` was not expected.

So can someone explain to me why the error is happening? As well as a possible solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing in your defined model is `result`, so it makes sense that it is confused about what to do with `<result>`; the root element of `ListCategories` as defined is: `<ListCategories>`. If that isn't what you expect, you can use attributes to tell it what it *should* be, for example `[XmlRoot("result")]` on the `class ListCategories`. But: we'd need to see what you *expect* to advise on the exact attributes.

If I had to *guess*:

```cs
[XmlRoot("result")]
public class ListCategories
{
    [XmlElement("category")]
    public List<Categories> CategoriesList { get; set; } = new List<Categories>();
}
```

Note you can lose the `[Serializable]`. That has nothing to do with xml serialization. You can also probably lose the `set` on `CategoriesList`.

Answer (score 0):

I've just had the same error and worked out eventually it was down to a typo in my Xml, so worthwhile checking the Xml to confirm that all the names match those in your class (my typo was in the class itself).

Also, I don't know if it makes any difference, but you have:

```
return (ListCategories)xml.Deserialize(fs);
```

in mine, I have List instead:

```
return (List<Category>)xml.Deserialize(fs);
```

and the xml is wrapped as 'ArrayOfMyClass':

```
<ArrayOfMyClass>
    <MyClass>
        <Prop1>Prop1Value</Prop1>
        <AnotherProp>AnValue</AnotherProp>
    </MyClass>
</ArrayOfMyClass>
```

In other words, whatever the underlying class is, wrap it in a tag prefixed with 'ArrayOf'.